# Deserializing with python requests in Django

Tags: python, json, django, request, deserialization

i'm trying to turn a json response into a list . So i can for example show all numbers or use them again to for example combine statistics from different pages. all_values = end_value.objects.all() <- i want that to work =).

I'm working in django1.8. and python 3.4.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: The response *is* a dict that you can use as many times as you like. What is the point of all this code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  all_values = end_value.objects.all() i want that to work

Comment: Excuse me, I was on a train. I'm not at your beck and call, for you to demand that I answer within five minutes.

Comment: DanielRoseman is one of the more helpful, prolific posters on this site. Perhaps the problem is you should spend more time learning and less time asking. Flagging this entire post as abusive

Comment: @user2266449 thank you for your feedback, one of my professors once said you will never learn something if you never ask questions. I thought this plattform was about that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and anyway, you have to ask a real question to get real help. So you need to provide example data in your question. A json response might be a dictionary, not a list. Posting your attempts so far to solve your own problem (i.e. actual code you've written to solve the problem) and where it does not work will get you answers. Just posting a generic question will get you generic answers.

Comment: @user2266449 as i did but after dealing with insults about my code i didn't leave it inside my post. You for example only made fun of my code without providing any help at all. The gentleman below helped me by telling me i had an endless loop i didn't see.

Comment: you are too sensitive. I did not make fun of your code, I just pointed out that doing a loop like that is a bad idea. Using exceptions to break out of loops will hide many many problems.

Comment: tell you what. Do all the tutorials here: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/ and then if you don't understand loops after that feel free to ask agian.

Comment: @user2266449 thanks, but i already signed into another payed tutorial. :/

Comment: do that anyway, it's great! It's what I get people started on when I teach them to code.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        #print(i)
        array = (content['data'][0])
        new = (array['values'][i])
        #end_value = (new['value'])
        end_value.extend(new['value'])
        #print(end_value)
        i +=1   

    except:
        break
```

This is why when you uncomment those lines it prints the contents but it never exit the loop, so you never execute render()

Consider using another condition in the while loop or use a for loop.

Comment: I don't get an error and it does render, but its just the last number. The loop is actually ending i can see that if i  look into the command line

Comment: posted an image above so you can see the loop is ending

Comment: No, he breaks the loop when an exception happens but he is passing the exception silently so maybe is a good idea to print or log the exception to know why it breaks.

Comment: it's a terrible idea to do a loop like that :P

Comment: O.O it's exactly 31 values so i thought it would break because it can't call any more index's. How can i get an error for that ?

Comment: Changed it into a for loop, but the core of the problem i want to actually turn it into a dict. =) any idea how i can do that?

Comment: yes, determine the key:value pairs you want, identify them and write them to a dictionary.